# strace shows long time reading from mysql socket - mysql takes long time to execute query?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, strace, file-descriptors

My Apache server takes long time to process request. I attached strace to it and can see the two following delays:

1) Very critical (143 seconds to process)

```
1335       0.000037 write(16, "\235\0\0\0\3INSERT INTO `br_anonymous_user_tokens` (`dtExpires`, `nmToken`, `dtCreated`) VALUES ('2014-08-25', '46e35dc39a41e836b806f48d21621b066ea182a9', '2014-06-25')", 161) = 161
1335       0.000111 read(16, "\t\0\0\1\0\1\374\262\n\2\0\0\0", 16384) = 13
1335     143.588134 gettimeofday({1403675497, 653337}, NULL) = 0
```

File descriptor #16 seems to be mysql socket:

```
line from strace
1335       0.000328 socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0) = 16
```

And here

```
pidof mysqld
15393
lsof -p 15393
mysqld  15393 mysql   12u  IPv4  26913133       0t0      TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
```

So it seems that Apache is waiting for mysql to execute the query which was written to the socket on the previous line. Am I right? Does it mean that I then need to understand why it takes so long for MySQL to execute simple query?

2) Very long

```
1335       0.000040 poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 0 (Timeout)
1335       5.005295 gettimeofday({1403675502, 686212}, NULL) = 0
```

Here I tried to locate file descriptor #14 to find out where the timeout comes from. I used techniques described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018981/poll-system-call-timeout), but none of them showed the descriptor in question. How can I find out where the timeout comes from?

Comment: Yes, you need to look through MySQL statistics to see why it takes so long to perform that query.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is resolved. I looked through the `PROCESSLIST` table in `information_schema` MySQL database and found that some tables are locked with the state `Waiting for table level lock`. So then I searched and found that one reason for the lock can be mysqldump backups - and this is exactly what I had configured recently. But because the job was misconfigured, it ran every minute constantly locking MySQL. Now that backups are configured correctly, the server works fine.

Yet the second question with `poll` remains unresolved.

Comment: Using `--single-transaction` with mysqldump will prevent table locks during the backup, if you are using InnoDB.

Comment: Great advice, thanks! What are the implications of using `--single-transaction`? And how should I use it if I make backups like this: `mysqldump -h example.com -u username -ppassword dbname | gzip > db.zip` ?